# Delay after opening a new tab using window.open();?

Tags: javascript, tabs, delay, window.open

I am looking for javascript code which will open new tabs(windows) automatically after specific interval of time.

Once first url is executed, setTimeout()/setIntervals()'s are ignored??
Please help!

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function open_win() {
setInterval(window.open("http://www.google.com"), 1000);
setInterval(window.open("http://www.yahoo.com"), 1000);
setInterval(window.open("http://www.bing.com"), 1000);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<input type=button value="Open Windows" onclick="open_win()">
</form>
</body>
```

Thank you

Comment: setInterval will contine to execute until you clear it. If you do get this to work you'll be continually opening new windows every second.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response Mike W, I'm sorry forgot to mention the first function is a "auto submit", during the processes of being submitted, it seems all timers become void and shorted..

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't want to use `setInterval` for this, [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval):

> Calls a function or executes a code snippet repeatedly, with a fixed time delay between each call to that function.

You want to use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) which:

> Calls a function or executes a code snippet after a specified delay.

The next problem is that `setTimeout` wants a function as its first argument but [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open) returns a reference to a window object. You want to wrap those `window.open` calls inside functions:

```
function open_win() {
    setTimeout(function() { window.open("http://www.google.com") }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function() { window.open("http://www.yahoo.com")  }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function() { window.open("http://www.bing.com")   }, 1000);
}
```

Your version would open the Google tab because the `window.open("http://www.google.com")` call would be executed while building the argument list for the first `setInterval` call. Presumably you're getting an exception or something from `setInterval` when you pass it a window reference so the rest of them aren't even reached.