# Javascript to open URLs at after a delay

Tags: javascript

I'm using [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18029730/8406858) to my liking, everything works well but I want a more solid script. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function open_win() {
    setTimeout(function() { window.open("http://example.com/t101.php") }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function() { window.open("http://example.com/t102.php")  }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function() { window.open("http://example.com/t103.php")   }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function() { window.open("http://example.com/t104.php")   }, 1000);

    setTimeout(function() { window.open("http://example.com/t105.php") }, 120000);
    setTimeout(function() { window.open("http://example.com/t106.php")  }, 120000);
    setTimeout(function() { window.open("http://example.com/t107.php")   }, 120000);
    setTimeout(function() { window.open("http://example.com/t108.php")   }, 120000);

    setTimeout(function() { window.open("http://example.com/t109.php") }, 240000);
    setTimeout(function() { window.open("http://example.com/t110.php")  }, 240000);
    setTimeout(function() { window.open("http://example.com/t111.php")   }, 240000);
    setTimeout(function() { window.open("http://example.com/t112.php")   }, 240000);
    
    }
</script>
<input type=button value="Start Scan" onclick="open_win()">
```

I open URLs as group of 4, each group takes less than 2 minutes and exact time of each group execution is not specific/know but less than 2 minutes.

Instead of opening each group at specific time I want to open each group when the first group closes and not wait for 2 minutes. All above links uses `window.close();` to auto close when executed.

Also any chance of opening 100s of links like this without putting in this function? All links ending as numbering like that.

I'm beginner in JavaScript. Apologies if it is no appropriate.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is here to help with code you wrote but SO is not here to write code for you.

Comment: So you want 100 links opened at once? If the names are the same, a loop that gets the index would suffice

Comment: Well if you want to detect the returning from another window then I am afraid you need a specific returning url.

Comment: To  that end, what have you tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your window.open calls into a variable like:

```
var a = window.open(/*url...*/);
```

Once that window has closed, it's `closed` property will be true. Just set up a setInterval() to check every second or so to check if it's closed then open a new window. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712195/js-listen-when-child-window-is-closed) has your answer for you. Something like the following could work:

```
var a = window.open("urla");
setInterval(function(){if (a.closed) {window.open("urlb");}}, 1000);
```

If you want to open 100 links, you could make a for loop that opens each link individually:

```
for (var a = 100; a < 200; a++) { window.open("http://example.com/t" + a + ".php"); }
```

^ will open links from 100 to 199.