# Javascript to open URLs after I close previous/tab?

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping

everyone

I've got 1000 links and I want every single one to be opened after i close previous/tab
Something like this:
I press "Start scan" do whatever I need to do with this site, than I close it down and the next link starts to open automatically

I'm trying this code

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function open_win() {
var a = window.open("https://www.zbozi.cz/vyrobek/klic-ockoplochy-26-mm-yato-yt-0355/");
setInterval(function(){if (a.closed) {window.open("https://www.zbozi.cz/vyrobek/klic-ockoplochy-27-mm-yato-yt-0027/");}}, 1000);
    }
</script>
<input type=button value="Start Scan" onclick="open_win()">
```

but i dont know how to add other links

I've got this code from here
[Javascript to open URLs at after a delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45538630/javascript-to-open-urls-at-after-a-delay)